# HDFS path does not exist with SparkSession object when spark master is set as LOCAL

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to load a dataset into Hive table using Spark.

But when I try to load the file from HDFS directory to Spark, I get the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/partfile;
```

These are the steps before loading the file.

```
val wareHouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
val SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]") \
    .appName("SparkHive") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","nonstrict") \
    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",wareHouseLocation).getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._
val partf = sparkSession.read.textFile("partfile")
```

Exception for the statement ->

```
val partf = sparkSession.read.textFile("partfile")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/home/cloudera/partfile;
```

But I have the file in my home directory of HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -ls
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         58 2017-06-30 02:23 partfile
```

I tried various ways to load the dataset like:

```
val partfile = sparkSession.read.textFile("/user/cloudera/partfile") and 
val partfile = sparkSession.read.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/partfile")
```

But nothing seems to work.

My spark version is 2.0.2

Could anyone tell me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the job by setting `master` as `local[2]`, your job is not getting submitted to spark master and so, spark does not know about underlying HDFS.
Spark will consider local file system as its default file system, and that's why, IOException occurs in your case.

Try this way:

```
val SparkSession = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("<spark-master-ip>:<spark-port>") \
    .appName("SparkHive").enableHiveSupport() \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","nonstrict") \
    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",wareHouseLocation).getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._
val partf = sparkSession.read.textFile("partfile")
```

You need to know `<spark-master-ip>` and `<spark-port>` for this.

This way, spark will take underlying hdfs file system as its default file system.

Comment: I tried:
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://localhost:7077").appName("Saving data into HiveTable using Spark").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", wareHouseLocation).getOrCreate()

I got to know the default port number from :https://github.com/holdenk/spark-old/blob/master/docs/spark-standalone.md

But it is still giving the error. Could you tell me if there is anything else to change ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for me what would be an error with explicit protocol specification but usually (as already was answered) it means that no neccesary configurations were passed into `Spark` context.

The first solution:

```
val sc = ??? // Spark Context
val config = sc.hadoopConfiguration
// you can mutate config object, it should work
config.addResource(new Path(s"${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/core-site.xml"))
// instead of adding a resource you can just specify hdfs address
// config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://host:port")
```

The second:

Explicitly specify `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` in `$SPARK_HOME/spark-env.sh` file. If you plan to use a cluster, be sure that every node of your cluster have `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` specified.

And be sure that you have all necessary Hadoop deps in your Spark / App classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should work.

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Appname").master("local[1]").getOrCreate();

DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = session.read();

String path = "path\\file.csv";

Dataset <Row> responses = dataFrameReader.option("header","true").csv(path);
```